Addition of a "morality" tag
I just added a morality tag. I felt that it was necessary because (a) we were starting to get a few questions about moral psychology; and (b) moral psychology is a legitimate and substantial subfield of psychology.
I added an initial tag excerpt:

For questions about moral reasoning, moral development, and the
  psychology of morality in general. Note that questions about whether
  something is or is not moral is typically more of a philosophical
  question, and will often not be suited to this site.

I tried to make it clear that the site is not really concerned with issues of whether something is or is not moral.
I thought I'd get comments and thoughts of others in case there were any issues.
I also wasn't quite sure whether moral-psychology would be a better name for the tag?
